# Test results duplicated when there are nested suites

Tags: phpunit

Nested test suites seem to cause results to be duplicated. Example: if I have this in `phpunit.xml`:

```xml
    <testsuite name="Unit Tests">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Integration Tests">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Integration</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="PubMed Tests">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Integration/PubMed</directory>
    </testsuite>
```

And create this test class:

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class PHPUnitDoublingTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testPhpUnitDoublesEverything()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Then run `phpunit --filter testPhpUnitDoublesEverything`.

With path `tests/Unit/PHPUnitDoublingTest.php` the output is:

`OK (1 test, 1 assertion)`

With path `tests/Integration/PubMed/PHPUnitDoublingTest.php` the output is:

`OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)`

This didn't happen when I was using v9. I started happening when I upgraded to v10. It's possible this is by design and I just don't understand how test suites are supposed to work. I can remove the nested the test suites and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. And I resolved it by setting the `defaultTestSuite` attribute. I also created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/5670

It's sad to see no replies here. Hope it helps.